# QCompleter and hashtag

Tags: qt

Im trying to get the `QCompleter` to trigger on hashtags `#`

Example:

I want to write #hello in my `TextEdit` and the `QCompleter` should find it in my `StringList`.

My current code:

```
completingTextEdit = new TextEdit;

QStringList stringList;
stringList << "#hello" << "#quit" << "#bye";
QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel(stringList);

completer = new QCompleter(completingTextEdit);
completer->setModel(model);
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
completer->setWrapAround(false);

completingTextEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

When I remove the `#` it works.

Any ideas how I can make `QCompleter` react to `#` ?

Comment: What is the `TextEdit` in your example? If I replace it with `QLineEdit`, it works fine for me.

Comment: Im using `TextEdit` to get multiline and avoid the blue highlight around the input

Comment: But Qt does not have a TextEdit class, but QTextEdit. QTextEdit does not have setCompleter() function, though.